# What kind of clause is operating here?

Tags: clauses, phrase-structure

In this sentence:

> This underlines once more **what a disastrous act of aggression the war in Iraq was**.

In essence: "This shows what a disaster it was".

"what [...] was" doesn't seem to be a free relative clause. What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This underlines once more what a disastrous act of aggression the war in Iraq was.

As what @gotube said,  the **what-clause** is not a relative clause.

A relative clause requires a relative pronoun,  like **who** or **which**, or relativiser **that**.

The clause

> what a disastrous act of aggression the war in Iraq was.

is a subordinate clause embedded in the main clause 'This underlines once more [clause].'

This subordinate clause is an exclamative clause serving as a complement (direct object) of the verb *underlines*.

> An exclamative sentence typically expresses an exclamation: "What a good friend you are!"

[wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(linguistics)#By_purpose)

Comment: That would actually make more sense to me, if we could call it an exclamation or exclamatory clause, as it seems a bit different than other wh- clauses I've seen. Unfortunately, I can't find mention of such a clause on the web or in my textbook.

Comment: Or, perhaps I mean to say, I haven't seen it talked about how an exclamatory sentence can be a subordinate clause.

Comment: Never mind. Got it! https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00437956.2005.11432550

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the phrase "what a disastrous act of aggression the war in Iraq was" is not a relative clause. It's a *noun clause*.

Let's rephrase it so it's clearer:

> Once more, this underlies [what a disastrous act of aggression the war in Iraq was].

or even simpler:

> Once more, this underlies [something].

It's clearer now that your clause is the *object* of the verb "underlies". If it's an object, that means it's a noun. If the clause can be replaced with a pronoun, it's a noun.

Relative clauses, in contrast, usually act as *adjectives* because they modify a previous noun.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Brooh Thanks! :) If you like the answer, consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Votes and accepts are the currency around here for valuable work.